# How can I print the passing string row by row in excel

Tags: java, selenium, katalon-studio

I am printing some string values in excel

In excel currently last string is printing, but I need to print them all row by row

Code

```
for(String a:arrOfStr)
{
    System.out.println(a);
    //CustomKeywords.'WriteExcel.demoKey'(a)
    CustomKeywords.'WriteExcel.demoKey'(a)
}
```

keyword

```
@Keyword
    public void demoKey(String name) throws IOException{

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\lahiruh\\Katalon Studio\\Project Decypha\\Decypha data files\\Demo1.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount+);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(name);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\lahiruh\\Katalon Studio\\Project Decypha\\Decypha data files\\Demo1.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
```

Now I can get the output like(overriding each value and giving last string ) [image: this]

I want to see like [image: this]

Comment: What is issue here ?

Comment: I need to print values row by row, currently, it's printing at same row and overriding each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrOfStr.size(); i++)
{
    String a = arrOfStr[i];
    System.out.println(a);
    //CustomKeywords.'WriteExcel.demoKey'(a)
    CustomKeywords.'WriteExcel.demoKey'(a,i)
}
```

@Keyword

```
public void demoKey(String name, int index) throws IOException{

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("path");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(index + 1);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(name);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("path");
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do in the following manner.

1. First create a set of rows
2. Create cell and define the cell data type.
3. Store the value in the cell

I provide below the structure to store the data row by row.

```
int rowNumber = 0; // Row number starting with 0

for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) { //This for loop can be your data set

    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber++);

    int columnNumber = 0; //Cell or Column number starting with 0
    for (j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) { //This for loop can be your data set
       Cell cell = row.createCell(columnNumber++);
       cell.setCellValue("Some string value");
    }
}
```